# Javascript/jQuery - "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined" while it IS defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In a simple script that goes through some form fields, gets the user input and stores it into arrays I ran into a problem.

It works when I do this:

```
var q1A = parseFloat($('#q1-1').val());
if(isNaN(q1A)) {
    var q1A = 0;
}
parameter.push(' ');
answers.push(q1A);
```

But now I added another array which, in this case, is supposed to simply store the same q1A variable. But somehow I end up with an "Uncaught TypeError" stating that the variable is undefined! The new code block is:

```
var q1A = parseFloat($('#q1-1').val());
if(isNaN(q1A)) {
    var q1A = 0;
}
input.push(q1A);
parameter.push(' ');
answers.push(q1A);
```

I logged the variable in the console and it works just fine, it's set and has a value. Any idea why it says it's undefined? The 'answers' array stores the value just fine.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Of course I defined the variables. I just didn't post that part of the code...

```
var groups = new Array();
var questions = new Array();
var input = new Array();
var parameter = new Array();
var answers = new Array();
var amounts = new Array();
```

Comment: `input` is not an array, you can't push to any variable, only to an array that has been previously defined.

Comment: I defined those. Added it to the post now.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mP6NT/1. If we cannot replicate the error, it's very difficult for us to help you. Please create your own http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which shows this problem.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will try to recreate the error there and come back to you guys!

Comment: Why are you redeclaring the variable q1A inside the if block?

Comment: Oh I'm not anymore, that was just sloppy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's possible to push an undefined variable into an array without error, the problem must be that `input` isn't defined when you try to call `push()` on it.

The usual reason for this problem is that there is another place where the variable `input` is declared and it's never initialized in the unexpected place.

Comment: It's about the input array, answers works fine. But regardless of which one it is, everything works fine if I remove the input array. But when I add it, the function stops as soon as it gets to the first push into that array. I only declared the arrays once, at the start of the function. I am trying to recreate the problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: Search your code for `var input`; I'm sure you'll find at least one result that you don't expect.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. You were right after all. Thanks! I did however declare input again after the point where the error occurred.

Comment: `var` has function scope; there is no block level scope in JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 4):

First you have to define as array.

```
var   input=[];
```

then try to push the element.

```
input.push(element);
```

Comment: I already declared the arrays, just didn't post that part of the code.