# Unable to push value in an Array in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to push a value into an array but I am getting error:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

My html code is:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items"  (click)="clicked(item.title)">
   {{item.title}}
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And my ts code is:

```
  clicked(item){

    this.addedtags.push(item);
    console.log(this.addedtags);     
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript/jQuery - "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined" while it IS defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882650/javascript-jquery-cannot-call-method-push-of-undefined-while-it-is-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addedtags array is undefined.
Initialize the array at the top of your class.

```
addedtags: any[] = []
```

Replace any with your specific datatype for cleaner code.

Comment: Good answer. I think it's good to mention that the piece you wrote needs to be at the top of the _class_ and not inside the function `clicked(item)` or it will be overwritten at each call